# Should asphalt crack sealant fill the cracks to completely level?

Tags: driveway, cracks, asphalt

I'm having a contractor crack-seal and seal-coat my asphalt driveway. They applied the crack seal yesterday and some of it looks like this:

[image: sealed cracks in asphalt driveway]

While there is crack-seal material in the cracks, it isn't level with the surface (the crack is still 10mm deep). I'm concerned that water will pool and freeze there. I'm also concerned that debris will fill it and weeds will grow in it.

Are they doing this the correct way? Should they be filling the crack-seal so that it's flush with the asphalt?

Edit:
The contractor came back, squeegeed in some fill material and then sealed over that. I didn't get a good look at the bucket that the fill material came out of, but it was about the consistency of sticky wet concrete.

Comment: That contractor did a crap job.  Either your cracks are very deep, or very wide, and the goop they used flowed into the crack after application.  Was that a heated sealant, or a sealant that was just squirted and spread (kinda looks the latter to me)?

Comment: It was a heated sealant. They used a push cart with a propane heater (in the cart). The cracks are rather deep.

Comment: They should be brought back to fill the cracks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be fully filled with sealant, although...

- The product shrinks quite a bit. It would take multiple applications to get to level.
- Most contractors don't plan or charge for that. Ask them. They may top it off at no extra cost.
- The product is flexible enough that freeze damage isn't really a concern over the top of it.
- Application of the actual sealer will fill the void further to some degree.
- The weed thing will happen regardless. No surface is ever entirely sealed. Keep some herbicide on hand.

Comment: If you don't like toxic herbicides, household vinegar is often enough for this purpose. Cheap too.